# Determining whether the relation R on the set of all web pages is reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric or Transitive

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, symmetry

I find these problems easy when it has to do with numbers, but I'm having trouble visualizing word problems.

The first question:

> "Everyone who has visited web page a has also visited web page b".

The answer is **Reflexive** and **Transitive**. But I'm having trouble visualizing why.

So let's say the webpages are `{Google, Yahoo, Bing, YouTube}`

So when I list it out would like `(Google, Google), (Yahoo, Yahoo), etc`
Where (a, b) is `person a and person b`

I don't understand if `(webpage a, webpage b)` correlates to `person a person b` is my question. Could someone help explain this overall problem?

Comment: If a person A visit Google, then trivially A visit Google. Thus, the relation Visit_A(x,y) - where x and y are web pages - is reflexive, for A whatever, i.e. Visit_A(x,x).

Comment: The relation Visit_A(x,y) is "a person A that Visit web-page x Visit also web-page y".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA so for person b, it would Visit_B(x,y)? Or do you only use Visit_A because it is arbitrary?

Comment: The issue is not with the "symbolization"; the issue is that the relation is between web-pages. Humans "visit" each other, but not (I think) in the same sense ...

Comment: In the formula defining this relation, the user variable is bound: $VisitorSubset(x, y) \iff (\forall a)(Person(a) \to (HasVisited(a, x) \to HasVisited(a, y))$. That is, the set of visitors to site $a$ is a subset of the set of visitors to $b$.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to realize that the relation is actually the subset relation on a certain family of sets. For each web page $w$ let $P(w)$ be the set of people who have visited $w$. If $R$ is the relation in question, then $\langle w_1,w_2\rangle\in R$ if and only if $P(w_1)\subseteq P(w_2)$: the set of people who have visited $w_1$ is a subset of the set of people who have visited $w_2$. Since $\subseteq$ is reflexive and transitive, $R$ should be as well, but we can verify this in detail.

- Clearly $P(w)\subseteq P(w)$ for every web page $w$, so $\langle w,w\rangle\in R$ for each web page $w$, and $R$ is therefore reflexive.
- If $\langle w_1,w_2\rangle\in R$ and $\langle w_2,w_3\rangle\in R$, then $P(w_1)\subseteq P(w_2)$, and $P(w_2)\subseteq P(w_3)$, so $P(w_1)\subseteq P(w_3)$. But that means that $\langle w_1,w_3\rangle\in R$ and hence that $R$ is transitive.